# Upper bound of the "number" of countable models of Th$\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

So basically I want to find out what is the upper bound of the "number" of countable models of

Th($\mathbb{N})$ up to isomorphism.

In the book by Richard Kaye, on Peano arithmetics, he simply said

"clearly there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ of countable models of Th($\mathbb{N}$)".

But regrettably, it was not clear to me why is this the case.

Any insight on this is deeply appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to isomorphism, a countable model can assumed to have underlying set $\mathbb{N}$.  So the model is determined by a choice of two elements of $\mathbb{N}$ to be $0$ and $1$ and two maps $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ to be addition and multiplication.  Thus there are at most $$|\mathbb{N}|\cdot|\mathbb{N}|\cdot|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}|\cdot|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}|=2^{\aleph_0}$$ countable models, up to isomorphism.

Comment: "Up to isomorphism, a countable model can assumed to have underlying set $\mathbb{N}$", I can't seem to convince myself on this, perhaps you can elaborate a little more on this part ?

Comment: If $M$ is any countable model, pick a bijection $f:M\to\mathbb{N}$, and then turn the operations on $M$ into operations on $\mathbb{N}$ using $f$.

Comment: +1. @some1fromhell Note that this is true for *any* theory $T$, as long as the language of $T$ is finite (note the number of choices we need to make here: two elements and two maps). E.g. there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$-many groups up to isomorphism, etc.

Comment: @NoahSchweber And even if the language is countable!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Whoops, yes, that was a typo. (Although the statement is  true, it is potentially confusing to the OP by suggesting that the result fails for all infinite languages!)